# Emacs find-file allowing to delete file

Tags: emacs, elisp

I remember sometime I had this setting in which I could delete a file when using `ido-find-file`; when I highlighted a file I could press `C-x C-k` and it would ask me to delete the file. Very convenient. How can I get this behavior again?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On my Emacs (24.3.5), it's still there. Just press `C-k`in `ido-find-file`.

Comment: Thanks, amazing that I missed that.